# How to create an "empty" image element in FabricJS?

Tags: fabricjs

I wondering if there is an option, first of all, to add an image element to a canvas (kind of initialize it), but then change it SRC and/or options?

Comment: What exactly you want? If you want to hide the object set `visible:false`

Comment: Based on all examples I've seen before, the way of adding an image to a canvas is by using image "onload" callback function. The problem in my case is that I'm getting a list of elements in particular order, but onload function will add an element asynchronously... So if you have RECT, IMAGE, RECT it could be rendered RECT, RECT, IMAGE...

Comment: After loading image you can use `sendBackwards()/moveTo(obj,index)`

Comment: Yes I know I can... I’m looking of way to pre-render first and then update arc and options...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `new fabric.Image('');` to initialise image object.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({left:20,top:20,width:50,height:50});
var image = new fabric.Image('');
var rect2 = new fabric.Rect({left:80,top:50,width:150,height:150,fill:'red'});
canvas.add(rect1,image,rect2);
console.log(canvas.getObjects())

function setSource(){
 image.setSrc('//fabricjs.com/assets/pug.jpg',function(img){
 img.set({  left:50,top:50, scaleX:300/img.width,scaleY:300/img.height});
 img.setCoords();
 canvas.renderAll();
 })
}
```

```css
canvas{
 border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<button onclick='setSource()'>setSource</button>
<canvas id='canvas' width=300 height=300></canvas>
```